# How to add ping list in Wordpress multi site?

Tags: multisite

As in wordpress multi site, wordpress removed "Ping List Text Area" from Setting->Writing added Text Field in Network-Admin->All-Sites->Edit->Settings, I'm not able to understand that How we should add Ping List Url in text field.
Eg.: 
http ://xyz [dot] com/rpc2 , http ://xyz1 [dot] com/rpc2
or
http ://xyz [dot] com/rpc2   http ://xyz1[dot]com/rpc2

Please explain that what we should use between two url, comma or space?

Comment: Please elaborate your question, I'm having trouble understanding what issue you're experiencing.

Comment: I mean in Setting->Writing, there is a text area where we can add ping list, one ping site in one line. But in Wordpress multisite this option is available in Network-Admin->All-Sites->Edit->Settings as a text box. But now I'm not able to understand that how we can add more then one ping sites in wordpress multi site?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install this plugin to activate the setting:

[Activate Update Services](https://wordpress.org/plugins/activate-update-services/)

Now you can see the "Update Services" setting from your subsite directly.

Hope this will help you and others.

Comment: hmmm, I am not sure this is what the question is about, and in any case as a network admin the last thing you will want to do is to configure this kind of setting per each site individually

Answer (score 0):

From the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Update_Services):

> By default, editing the Ping Services for a WordPress Multisite
>   network site is disabled. This can be re-enabled with a plugin such as
>   the [Activate Update Services](https://wordpress.org/plugins/activate-update-services/) plugin.